# Очистка данных массива после отправки данных

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, plpgsql

Существующая форма предназначена для коррекции данных внесённых в БД Postgres.
Вызов данных, коррекция и обновление записей в БД.
После вызова и заполнения элементов массива данными из Postgres

```js
<?php>
$qexist = "SELECT 
       test.tb.id_bld, 
       test.tb.street, 
       test.tb.bld_no, 
  FROM test.tb
  WHERE test.tb.street = '$street'
  AND test.tb.bld_no = '$bld_no'
  "; 
  $ress = pg_query($qexist);
  while ($row = pg_fetch_array($ress)) { 
        $val[11] = $row[11];
        $val[12] = $row[12];
        $val[13] = $row[13];
        $val[14] = $row[14];
  }
 ?>
```

вставки их в поля формы  и коррекции данных

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="Shop">Shop:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="shop" value="<?php echo $val[11] ?>">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><label for="Services">Services:</label>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text"  name="services" value="<?php echo $val[12] ?>">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="Category of building">Investment Category:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $val[13] ?>">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="Manager_id">Manager ID</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="id_manager" value="<?php echo $val[14] ?>">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="<?php echo date ('Y-m-d H:i:s')?>">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" onClick="return nodata(this.form)" name="query" value="Query">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" onClick="return nodata(this.form)" name="update" value="Update" id="upDate">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear It">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

отправки откорректированных данных назад в БД

```js
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
  $data = array(
    'shop' => $val[11],
    'services' => $val[12],
    'category' => $val[13],
    'id_manager' => $val[14]     
 );
  $elem = $_POST;
  foreach($elem as $key => $value)

  unset($elem['update']);

  $res = pg_update($dbconn, 'test.tb', $elem, $data);
  if ($res) {
    echo "Updated: $res\n";
  } else {
    echo "Data not sent\n";
  }
}
```

данные последнего запроса остаются в элементах массива `$val[]`, а учитывая то, что эти элементы жестко привязаны к полям формы `value="<?php echo $val[x] ?>`, эти данные продолжают находиться в поле, несмотря на команду `unset ( $elem ['update'] );` и естественно не убираются из полей кнопкой `type=reset` в стандартном варианте.
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким кодом привязанным к кнопке Reset можно очистить (обнулить значения) содержимого элементов массива и тогда предыдущие значения пропадут из формы без всякой её специальной очистки.
Если возможно очистить массив сразу после отправки данных кнопкой Update, добавив функцию очистки (обнуления данных) массива к `unset`, это было бы идеально, чтобы не загромождать форму кнопками. Спасибо

Comment: отправка формы стандартным формовым постом или аяксом? все листинги из одного файла? почему просто не уйти со страницы редактирования, или это не отдельная страница а лишь часть большой страницы?

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin... код отправки формы опубликован... всё в одном файле... уходить со страницы редактирования неудобно, сейчас используем как вариант, но это примитивное решение, когда надо просмотреть и отредактировать 100 записей